# `/usr/local/clang6/lib/libomp.dylib` not found on Mac when using R

Tags: r, macos, macos-mojave, dyld

I downloaded the lastest R R-3.5.3.pkg and installed on my Mac (OS X 10.14.1).

Then I installed `littler` with `install.packages('littler')`.

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/littler_0.3.7.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 606052 bytes (591 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 591 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /tmp/mktemp/RtmpOW3zHj/downloaded_packages
```

```
$ $HOME/Library/R/3.5/library/littler/bin/r
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/clang6/lib/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/xxx/Library/R/3.5/library/littler/bin/r
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Is there a way to fix the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is there further output, when you try to install the package? Looks like a compiler issue for me

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the OMP support that comes with clang6. Simon Urbanek makes that compiler available at the CRAN website: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/ . You should install both clang6 and gfortran 6.1 if you expect to compile R packages from source (or if you need facilities that come with them that are not provided by MacOS.)